# jQuery Mobile - Radio button before change

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

What I'm trying to achieve is to stop the value change of a radio button set when an option is tapped. If a variable is true when an option is tapped then return false and avoid the visual and value change.

Something like this:

```
AvoidChange = true;
$(document).on('beforechange','[type=radio]',function(){
    if( AvoidChange==true )
        return false;
    });
```

I know `beforechange` can't be applied to radio buttons but... How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: the only way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uvD5E/

Comment: To be honest I don't know if jQuery mobile can do this but jQuery can: Just disable options. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qqVGu/ I think you can do that with $('#selector').prop('disabled', true) or something like that

Comment: @user2718671 another brilliant idea. jQM can do it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xRayQ/

Comment: @Omar i am not clear with this question. we can do like this http://jsfiddle.net/xRayQ/4/ is that he expecting or...

Comment: @Aravinth he wants to stop "change" if a condition is true.

Comment: @Omar then your answer is work well for his condition.

Comment: @Aravinth let him try it first ;)